# How to avoid Pygame changing female voice into male

Tags: python, audio, pygame, audio-player, frequency-analysis

I am trying to play an audio file of a female, speaking something in hindi using pygame library in python. When i manually click on audio file and listen to it, it is a female voice, but when but I play it via below script, I get a male voice. I guess it is converting female frequency into male. Why is that and how to avoid it?

Note: I am using Raspbian on Raspberry Pi.

This is the link to the audio file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=18pLBoCMxWZzB-RO3qqVmi0zREgJckb3M

My coding:

```
import pygame.time
from pygame.mixer import *
pre_init()
init()
filename = 'speech.wav'
music.load(filename)
music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
```

Comment: Sounds implausible. The audio plays as female for me. What's the sampling rate? I'm vaguely guessing you are playing a 44 kHz file at 22 kHz and the lowered frequencies make it sound like a male voice.

Comment: Yea the audio us just playing slower, around 2 times as slow - meaning triplee is correct. Try `pygame.mixer.init(frequency=32000)` *(Your audio file is 32000 Hz, not 22 or 44)*

Answer (score 1):

```
import pygame.time
from pygame.mixer import *
pre_init()
init(frequency=32000)
filename = 'speech.wav'
music.load(filename)
music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
```

`pygame.mixer.init()` takes a [frequency](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.init) parameter. And since the player defaults to `22050`, the playback will be in slowm-otion - making it sound different. You can circumvent this by changing the speed manually, or you can probably get the actual speed from `music.load()`, the meta-data should be in the file.

Otherwise, just do `ffmpeg -i speech.wav` and you'll see the correct frequency at the bottom.

To change the frequency of audio-files to match the same frequencies, you could use ffmpeg to re-encode the files. Now, I'm no magician with ffmpeg - but the just goes something along the lines of:

```
ffmpeg -i speech.wav -af asetrate="32000*1.38125,atempo=1/1.38125" output.wav
```

Or use Audacity or something others recommend: https://superuser.com/questions/292833/how-to-change-audio-frequency

A second option to change frequency on the player instead, is to call `pygame.mixer.quit()` after each media file and re-initiate it with a new frequency matching your new file. Or lastly, read the docs and see if it's possible to change frequency playback on a already initialized instance of the mixer. This is beyond my knowledge tho. I just know what your original root problem is :)

Comment: What if we have multiple files having diff frequencies and we want to play them one after another?

Comment: @user9181286 You have three options. The easiest being, re-encode the audio files to have matching frequencies. That will get you along the fastest. The second being re-initiate the media player after each clip (`init()` and `pygame.mixer.quit()` at the end of each media). The third being to investigate and see if the media handle supports in-instance changes to the frequency. I've only dabbled with `Pyglet`, not `Pygame`, so I'm not sure if this is possible. Read up on the docs, or try `music.frequency=32000` or `pygame.mixer.freqency=32000` (do `import pygame.mixer` instead of `from...`)